# Assigning image from another View Controller class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a unassigned UIImageView in one View Controller class. I want to assign it using UIImage ImageNamed:@"examplePic.png" from another View Controller class's .m file

Here is my code -

```
Class1.h
//The class with the unassigned UIImageView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;
//The UIImageView is connected to the @property


Class2.m
//
Class1 *class1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];
class1.myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"examplePic.png"];
```

Comment: when do you want to assign it? are you working with storyboards and performing a segue from viewcontroller A to viewcontroller B?

Comment: does class 1 have a storyboard associated with it where the image view is wired up to the iboutlet?  Or are you creating the image view in viewdidload?    At what point are you presenting class 1's view on screen?

Comment: You need to use [delegates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) for this

Comment: Maybe you can use `prepareforsegue` method to pass image named          - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {   //    NewViewController obj= [segue destinationviewcontroller]; // and then // obj.imageName = self.imageName; }   And create a string to new .m file and you can send thatstring from current view controller to NewViewController using prepare for segue method

Comment: I am using Xib's with each class

Comment: Class1.h, Class1.m, Class1.xib

Comment: And I control-click drag the UIImageView on the XIB and connect it to the @property

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `UIImageView` is not being initialized before you attempt to set its `image` property. Try the following:

```
class1.myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"examplePic.png"]]
```

Comment: The image still does not appear @NolanDC

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `UIImageView` has not been initialised yet. To fix this:

Add a new property for an UIImage:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *imageForImageView;
```

When initialising your `UIViewController` which will be pushed onto the stack try this:

```
UIViewController *someViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeNibName" bundle:nil];
someViewController.imageForImageView = image;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```

Then in your `viewDidLoad` of `someViewController` you can assign `imageForImageView` as image to your `UIImageView`.

This way you ensure that the `UIImageView` actually is in memory when assigning an `UIImage` to it.